# CodeLite isn't showing some of the created projects

Tags: ide, codelite

[image]so my problem is that in CodeLite under created workspace there are some projects missing that I already worked on, an when I try to add them manually, an error saying that I should check if codelite has a permission to write on a disc. Any suggestions? 
Thank you very much.

EDIT: ScreenShot of the error

Comment: unix permissions? open as administrator?

Comment: It's quite impossible to recreate this problem for anyone else. Maybe you could post the error messages/screen shots? Also, this has nothing to do with C or C++.

Comment: Provide OS, codelite version...

Comment: W10 an CodeLite 12.0.8